# Keras Variable Sized Mask or Slice

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm working on an Super Resolution (5x) CNN that operates on single channel images with input shape `(None, None, None, 1)`

Assume an image with a top row of

`[x, x, x, x, x, y, y, y, y, y]`

which downscaled 5x becomes

`[x, y]`

Consider a network made of a single `Conv2DTranspose` layer with 5x5 stride and a single constant ones matrix 9x9 filter. Applying this to `[x, y]` yields

`[x, x, x, x, X, x+y, x+y, x+y, x+y, Y, y, y, y, y]`

(here the `X`, `Y` denote the center of the set of pixels generated from `x`, `y`)

So we've gone from a 2 column matrix, to a 14 column matrix.

One way of comparing this upscaled output to the original image, is to pad the original image with `(filter_size - stride_size)/2 = (9-5)/2 =2` entries on each side

`[0, 0, x, x, x, x,     x,   y,  y,  y, y, y, 0, 0]`

which then lines up nicely with our upscaled version of downscaled image

`[x, x, x, x, X, x+y, x+y, x+y, x+y, Y, y, y, y, y]`

At this point I'm ready to take the difference between these two rows and calculate loss.

However, the artificial 4 boundary points will contribute to the loss.  I clearly don't care about the error in this artificial boundary region.  How can I ensure these values are not included in the loss?

I've considered custom losses, slices, and masking layers, but the issue is that the input being variable size.  If the input was of fixed size I could create a masking tensor or update the values based on the fixed sizes, but with variable input size I need to create a variable masking tensor.

````
import keras
import numpy as np
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (9,9), strides=(5,5), input_shape=(None, None, 1),
        kernel_initializer='ones', bias_initializer='zeros'))
#x is downscaled image
x = np.zeros([1,2,2,1])
x[0,0,0,0] = 1
x[0,0,-1,0] = .5

#y is original image
y = np.zeros([1,10,10,1])
y[0,0,:,0]= [1,1,1,1,1,.5,.5,.5,.5,.5]

y_pred = model.predict(x)

paddings = ((0,0),(2,2),(2,2),(0,0))
y_pad = np.pad(y, paddings, mode='constant')

# want keras to calculate loss of
# y_pad[:,2:-2,2:-2,:] - y_pred[:,2:-2,2:-2,:]```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the simplest way to trim out the padding layer is to to use a Conv2D layer with fixed kernel and bias and no padding.

```
depad_kernel = np.zeros([2*padding+1,2*padding+1])
depad_kernel[padding, padding,0,0] = 1

depad_bias = np.zeros([1])

depadded_output = model.add_layer(
        keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (2*padding+1, 2*padding+1), strides=(1,1),
                            weights=[depad_kernel, depad_bias], trainable=False))
```

UPDATE

Looks like there is a way simpler way of doing by applying a cropping layer to the output of the model, this can be used to remove the extraneously generated points.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Cropping2D